# convergence of $\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the infinite sum $\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n}$ converge ?
Can anyone help ?

Comment: What are your thoughts and efforts on the problem so far? Can you think of any tests that would apply in this situation? (Write out the first several terms of the series to see if that gives you any ideas.)

Comment: The answers to your questions are "No" and "Yes". Now, what did you try?

Comment: Pairing consecutive terms work.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can't use the alternating series test here.

Comment: No the series isn't decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider  $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left(a_{2k}+a_{2k+1}\right)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2k}+1}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}-1}\right)=$
$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{2k+1}-\sqrt{2k}}{(\sqrt{2k}+1)(\sqrt{2k+1}-1)}-\dfrac{2}{(\sqrt{2k}+1)(\sqrt{2k+1}-1)}\right)$.

The serie of the first terms converges (because the members are $\sim \frac{1}{const\cdot k^{3/2}}$), and the second terms are $\sim \frac{1}{const\cdot k}$ and so this serie diverges. So the serie in question diverges.

Comment: Sorry, but why does $\frac{1}{C k}$ diverge?